# Optimized build is giving error

Tags: qooxdoo

Don't know what did I do wrong but "Optimized build" of my Qooxdoo (1.0.1) application stopped working. Still source build and non-optimized build are working without any trouble. An idea how to find the bug?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Some objects were null. I can't tell exact phrase as it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check which optimization causes the problem. Most likely, you are using a private method which starts with __ (two underscores). These variable names will be renamed during the optimization.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes my first problem was due to using private member outside of the class that is fixed. But still facing similar issue with a protected member (single underscore) though it is being called in subclasses only. Am I still doing a mistake?